# Finding points on the parabola at which normal line passes through it

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Hello guys I need help with the problem: Find the points on the parabola $y = x^2 - 4x + 3$ at which normal line passes through $(2, 0)$.

What I did: I first took a derivative of the equation which equals to $2x - 4$. Then I have the equation $y - y_1 = (2x - 4)(x - x_1)$. $y$ is $2$ and $x$ is $0$ here. But I'm not sure how to find $y_1$ and $x_1$ here. I'm thinking that when I get the final equation, I can plug in $(2, 0)$ and get the points.

Am I approaching this problem correctly? It seems like a simple problem, but it confuses me

Comment: Instead of $(2x-4)$ you need $(2x_1-4)$.

Comment: You might think about it this way. For which pair $(x,y)$ on the curve is the line through $(x,y)$ and $(2,0)$ normal to the curve at $(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x,y)$ be such a point, so $y=x^2-4x+3$.

The tangent line at $(x,y)$ has slope $2x-4$ as you found, so the normal line has slope

$\;\;\;\displaystyle m=-\frac{1}{2x-4}=-\frac{1}{2(x-2)}$.

Since this line passes through $(x,y)$ and $(2,0)$, its slope $\displaystyle m=\frac{y-0}{x-2}=\frac{x^2-4x+3}{x-2}$.

Now set these two expressions for the slope equal to each other and solve for x, and then

substitute back into the equation of the parabola to get the y-coordinates (which in this case are equal).