# Does the normal line exist at $x=2$ given a parabola $f(x)=x^2-4x+3$?

Tags: calculus

So the problem is:

Find the points on the parabola $f(x)=x^2-4x+3$ at which the normal line passes through the point $(2,0)$.

---

Since $f'(x)=2x-4$, then the normal line is $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{2x-4}$. At $x=2$, $f$ has a horizontal tangent, which implies $f'(2)=0$.

Does this mean that $\textbf{(1)}$ the normal line is parallel to $y$, passing through the point $(2,0)$ since it is perpendicular to the tangent line at $x=2$? or $\textbf{(2)}$ it does not exist at this point since it is undefined at $x=2$ and graphing $\displaystyle\frac{-1}{2x-4}$ I get a curve that is not perpendicular to the tangent line at $x=2$ at all? or neither .. please help me understand. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153622

Comment: @user84413 Thanks. I'm aware of that one. It's from the same problem, but my questions are about the problem itself, so hopefully this doesn't get closed ..

Comment: I see what you're saying -- it's the same problem, but you are asking what the problem actually means.  You are correct in thinking that the normal line at (2,-1) is the line x=2, but this is not what the question is asking for, as tomi points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not asking for the normal at the point (2,0). It is asking for the normal(s) that go through (2,0).

Consider the normal at point $(x=p,y=p^2-4p+3)$. It has gradient $m=-\frac {1}{2p-4}$.

Substituting these into $y=mx+c$ yields:

$$p^2-4p+3=-\frac {1}{2p-4} p +c$$

$$c=p^2-4p+3+\frac {p}{2p-4}$$

$$y=-\frac {x} {2p-4}+p^2-4p+3+\frac {p}{2p-4}$$

If the normal goes through (2,0) then

$$0=-\frac {2} {2p-4}+p^2-4p+3+\frac {p}{2p-4}$$

$$0=p^2-4p+3+\frac {p-2}{2p-4}$$

$$p^2-4p+3.5=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The vector $(1,f'(x))$ is tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $(x,f(x))$. Hence the vector $(-f'(x),1)$ is normal to the graph at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

If two lines have gradients $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that $m_1 m_2=-1$, then they are perpendicular.

But there are perpendicular lines that do not fit this description. Lines of the form $y=a$ are perpendicular to lines of the form $x=b$.